# Usage of lstrcpy in linux

Tags: c++, linux

What is the equivalent of lstrcpy in linux?

How it is different from strcpy?

Comment: there is no function strlcpy.

Comment: `strncpy`, but it doesn't quite do the same thing.

Comment: @DavidHammen: they do quite different things, in fact. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/07/348437.aspx

Comment: OT: At least on Debian systems you find the commands `strlcpy` and `strlcat` in the package `libbsd-dev`. Anyway `lstrcpy()` and `strlcpy()` are not equivialents. @user1616699

Answer (score 1):

`lstrcpy` is a windows API which copies the appropriate character size for your build (either `wchar` or `char` depending on how you build the application). There isn't a direct linux equivalent (in that you have to know which to use, without the compiler working it out for you), but `wcscpy` copies `wchar*` strings.